# How to access and replace values in a dict-list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

[python]

I have a multi-stage dict-list. I want to access the location in the dict-list and replace it with list `data` and `data_result`. I am able access the location and append to the values to a variable. However, I don't know how to create a variable that stores the entire dict-list and the replaced/appended list.

Multi-stage structure, focusing on `data` and `results` list

### [image: multi-stage structure]

Note: all parameters are set to a value.

```
data = {
    "uuid": str(uuid),
    "name": str(tag + "_" + testName + "_" + str(datetime.datetime.utcnow())),
    "verdict": str(totalResult)
}
print(data)

    data_result = {
        "Test_Case": str(Test_Case),
        "Test_Result": str(result),
        "Time Evaluation": str(duration)
    }

    res = tcm_template ## ** HERE **
    res2 = tcm_template['testcatalogmanager']['ut']['tests']
    for res3 in res2:
        res4 = res3['data']
        for res5 in res4: # # res4 in data list     
            final_result = res5['results']
            final_result.append(data_result)


#tcm_template.replace(data) ## @ data - prototype code
#tcm_template.append(final_result) ## @ results - prototype code
```